# overrepresentation test, between transcriptome and candidates sequences obtained from the transcriptome

Tags: statistics, transcriptome, go-enrichment

For an analysis of my data, I have a transcriptome and a list of sequences obtained from the transcriptome. I would like to perform a functional enrichment analysis. I have annotated both sets of data using eggnog mapper. Currently, I want to perform a test between the two functional annotations, specifically COGs (Clusters of Orthologous Groups). I have tried using the R code https://yulab-smu.top/biomedical-knowledge-mining-book/enrichment-overview.html#gsea-algorithm
with clusterProfiler, but it seems that it may not work. With which tools or code can I perform this test, please?

exemple somme of my data :

[image]